# Is there a replacement for AUSplitter in iOS?

Tags: ios

AUSplitter takes an audio signal and makes multiple copies of it.  However, it is only available on OS X.  How can I achieve the same effect in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom class called Splitter.  The Splitter class allows you to set its upstream audio unit.

It also has a render method similar to AudioUnitRender.  When its render method is called it alternates between asking its upstream audio unit to render and buffering the rendered data and simply returning the buffered copy of the last render operation.

Its only a 1-2 Splitter and it doesn't handle format conversions, but it worked for what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, the `kAudioUnitSubType_Splitter` audio unit was added in iOS 6. From the AUComponent headers:

```
enum {
    kAudioUnitSubType_AUConverter           = 'conv',
    kAudioUnitSubType_Varispeed             = 'vari',
    kAudioUnitSubType_DeferredRenderer      = 'defr',
    kAudioUnitSubType_Splitter              = 'splt',
    kAudioUnitSubType_Merger                = 'merg',
    kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch          = 'nutp',

#if !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    kAudioUnitSubType_TimePitch             = 'tmpt',
    kAudioUnitSubType_RoundTripAAC          = 'raac'
#else
    kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodTime            = 'iptm',
    kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodTimeOther       = 'ipto'
#endif
};
```